# Wiper motor availability in 12v and 30 amps?

Tags: capacity

Is there any availability of 30 amps in 12v wiper motor  and what is the maximum power of a wiper motor availability. I want to utilise the high watt wiper motor for different application.

Comment: Yes goto junkyard and buy parts for truck or big car

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiper motors will probably not exceed 50 watts (4.2 amps at 12 volts). A 30 amp motor will require 360 watts and probably produce at least 250 watts of mechanical power. An engine cooling fan or cabin heating/cooling fan might approach that power level. Engine cranking (starter) motors produce much more power, usually 1 to 1.5 kW, but they are designed to operate for only the short time that it takes for the engine to start. I found this information in some survey data in a 1996 paper "The Present Status of Electrical Machines in Vehicles" by J G W West Consulting Engineer. I don't have a link.

Comment: Sir in some papers (DESIGN, DEVELOPMENT AND TESTING OF NOVEL REMOTE 
CONTROLLED ELECTRICALLY OPERATED HYDRAULIC JACK 
Deepa A., Naveen Krishna Baru and Sagarnath G.
School of Mechanical Engineering, VIT University, Vellore, India)  I have observed that they are using wiper motors to lift the automobiles by connecting to an hydraulic Jack with mechanism. How it is possible without availability of wiper motor in high watt capacity?

Comment: that's the hydraulic advantage - like a lever...

Comment: 1996 - hmm motors have moved on a bit....

Comment: @JagadishKumar Judging by the picture of the motor shown at the end of the paper, and by the fact that it was being used in a battery-powered device, it's very unlikely that the motor in use was actually 30A (360W). The paper is rather amateurishly written -- it's almost certainly just wrong on that detail.

Comment: Yes @Solar Mike, motors have moved on a bit in the direction of increased efficiency. Vehicle design has likely moved a bit in the direction of less wasted power in the mechanics of electric motor driven auxiliary equipment. The odds of finding a motor with a 250 W output o salvage have probably diminished. A larger vehicle may still have such a motor. A wheelchair of golf cart motor is another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

check out seat motors or better yet cooling fan motors : if you look at the size of the wires supplying a wiper motor then it is obvious that it does not take 30 A continuously.

Some cooling fans have that sort of rating though and have large relay / controllers to drive them.